# Fourier transforms of Marcum Q function

Tags: fourier-analysis, special-functions

I cannot find in the literature the following:

$$\int_0^{\infty}\,Q_1(a,bx)\,\cos(\omega x)\,\,dx$$

and

$$\int_0^{\infty}\,Q_1(a,bx)\,\sin(\omega x)\,\,dx$$

with $a,\omega>0$.

$Q_1(a,x)$ is the [Marcum Q function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcum_Q-function) of order 1.

Does anybody have any idea?
Thanks!